# How to overcome rate limit of Facebook graph API? Is there any subscription for that?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How to overcome rate limit of Facebook graph API? I know programatic way of checking rate limit but i want to know is there any paid/unpaid way so that i need to stuck in the rate limit problem? Is there any subscription for that?

Comment: You should ask this question somewhere else. Try Facebook support first.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't :), there is not much you can do about it beside changing your call interval, try to lazy load data. (So only when you need to show it to the user, then load it)